# Migrating An Angular App from version11 to version12 Issue

Tags: angular

After finishing installing all the dependencies according to :
https://update.angular.io/

I run in the terminal : ng serve & I get these errors :

```
./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
    ╷
289 │             @if ($color != null and $contrast != null) {
    │                                     ^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  src\@fuse\scss\partials\_colors.scss 289:37  fuse-color-classes()
  src\@fuse\scss\partials\_colors.scss 362:1   @import
  src\@fuse\scss\core.scss 26:9                @import
  src\styles.scss 2:9                          root stylesheet
    at processResult (C:\Users\user\Downloads\sa\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:713:19)
    at C:\Users\user\Downloads\sa\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:819:5
    at C:\Users\user\Downloads\sa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:400:11
    at C:\Users\user\Downloads\sa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:252:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\user\Downloads\sa\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.callback (C:\Users\user\Downloads\sa\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:54:7)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Downloads\sa\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\sass\sass-service.js:134:25)
    at Worker.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (internal/worker.js:207:53)
    at MessagePort.[nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (internal/event_target.js:354:41)
    at MessagePort.exports.emitMessage (internal/per_context/messageport.js:18:26)


ng -- version 

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1202.17
@angular-devkit/build-angular      12.2.17
@angular-devkit/core               12.2.17
@angular-devkit/schematics         12.2.17
@angular/animations                12.2.13
@angular/cdk                       12.2.13
@angular/cli                       12.2.17
@angular/flex-layout               10.0.0-beta.32
@angular/material                  12.2.13
@angular/material-moment-adapter   12.2.13
@angular/router                    12.2.13
@schematics/angular                12.2.17
rxjs                               6.5.5
typescript                         4.3.5
```

By the way the application was working fine in version11 & all the dependencies were installed correctly but I didn't figure out what's happenning plzzz help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well. You are having problem with resolving your SCSS/Less import paths.

I had to replace previous paths which looked like this `@import 'styles/utils/_variables.less'` into `@import '../../../../styles/utils/_variables.less'`.

Later I found much better solution. Simply add following config into `angular.json` build step.

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   "includePaths": ["src/", "src/styles/"]
 },
```

And then you can use something like this right away `@import 'utils/_variables.less'`

Comment: When I added : 
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   "includePaths": ["src/", "src/styles/"]
 },
in the angular.json it shows me :
Property stylePreprocessorOptions is not allowed. 
unfortunately nothing is fixed.

Comment: @salahelmejri check out https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration to ensure it is configured correctly and in the right place